# Replace String in File with SED

Tags: sed, regular-expression

The contents of the file as as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<sites>
  <site>
    <url>https://host.com/path/another-path/stable-1.630/update-center.json</url>
  </site>
</sites>
```

I tried the following:

```
sed -i '' -e "s/stable-\d+.\d+/stable-2.233/g" ${FILE_PATH}
```

**Essentially, my intention is to replace the version number after 'stable-'.** However, it doesn't seem to be replacing the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach could be to make your regexp less "picky" about the version number.  One could assume that the string you're searching for is the string `stable-` followed by any number of non-slash characters.  However, since this regexp itself will contain a slash, it becomes convenient to use a delimiter **other** than `/` within the `sed` expression itself.  This example uses `%` as the delimiter for `sed`'s `s` command:

```
sed -i '' -e "s%stable-[^/]*%stable-2.233%g" ${FILE_PATH}
```